# What is a better practice for the following HTML tags?

Tags: html

I've tried `<strong><em>webpage</em></strong>` and `<strong><em>webpage</strong></em>`. Both of them display the same content in the same way. However, I have the feeling that one of the practices is a better one in terms of readability and preventing bugs/mistakes. What's your take on this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

Browser is one forgiving piece of software, so it doesn't `scream`, `curse` or `swear` when you do funky stuff like that but instead tries to make sense of it and shows the same stuff.

Of course it's better with the first form, for readability and it makes more sense for spiders crawling your sites, and in fact, I'd say the second form is invalid HTML

Comment: So if I use the 2nd form, it's harder for crawlers to make sense of what I'm doing?

Comment: that was metaphorical. It really depends on how the spider is programmed :)

Answer (score 3):

```
<strong><em>webpage</em></strong>
```

Answer (score 3):

The tags should be nested, so first close the inner tag(s), then the outer
=> your first form is the only valid form.

btw., do you realy need `<strong>` and `<em>` on one element?

Comment: Probably not, but I'm using it as an example to prove a point.

Answer (score 1):

```
<strong><em>webpage</em></strong>
```

You are opening a strong tag and then an em tag inside the strong, therefore you should close the em tag before the strong tag.